# how to insert in sorted order

Tags: c++, insert, find, std

I know that `std::find()` helps to find the iterator position of a given value. And `std::insert()` insert a given value into the container at a known position.

However, is there any function I can call which returns which position a new value should be inserted into according to alphabetical order in standard library?

For example, if a queue is A23, A34, B59, D49.
If a supplement C50, then a function like `std::foo()` returns the position between B59 and D49. So I can then call `std::insert()` to finish the job?

Answer (score 0):

The pair of functions `std::lowerbound` and `std::upperbound` will give you an iterator to an insertion point that will keep a vector in sorted order. If an element with the same value already exists, `lowerbound` will give an insertion point at the front of the existing value while `upperbound` will give the point behind.  Use `upperbound` if you want stable sorting.